# IOS Whatsap Kill my Background Localisation APP

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, cllocationmanager

I have an application that makes the location trace in background. As soon as I get WhatsApp or the phone my location stops and resumes after seeing the image. Would anyone have information on this problem?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrmyR.png)

```
- (void) startUpdatingLocationFonction
{
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
self.locationManagerStartDate = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
[AppDelegate sharedInstance].latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
[AppDelegate sharedInstance].longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

if (![[FoncGlobal sharedFoncGlobal] isValidLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation withOldLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation])
    return;

if ((oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    || (oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude))
    {
    [[FoncGlobal sharedFoncGlobal] upDateTraceUser: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8lf",newLocation.coordinate.latitude]: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8lf",newLocation.coordinate.longitude] :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8lf",newLocation.altitude]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8lf",newLocation.speed]:0];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
if (_inBackground) {
    [self extendBackgroundRunningTime];
   }
}

 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
[self extendBackgroundRunningTime];
_inBackground = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
_inBackground = NO;
}
- (void)extendBackgroundRunningTime {
    if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Attempting to extend background running time");

    __block Boolean self_terminate = NO;

    bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"DummyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Background task expired by iOS");
        if (self_terminate) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        while (true) {

        if ([AppDelegate sharedInstance].startTrack)
            [self startUpdatingLocationFonction];

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: you mean when application backgrounded, can you provide more info ?

Comment: Yes, see code ci-dessus

Comment: Why are you using background tasks?  How are you setting up your CLLocationManager?  You must call `startUpdatingLocation` in the foreground if you want updates to continue indefinitely in the background

Comment: I call CClocation manager in mainview and also in appDelegate